# Mysql stops with no visible reason

Tags: mysql, logging

Third day in a row I find my sites down.
Reason: mysql not running.
Doing sudo mysql restart — and everything is up again (for few hours).
But why the hell mysql has stopped?

Here are the last lines of log:

```
              482 Connect   zslon_sweetbread@localhost on zslon_sweetbread
              482 Query     SET NAMES 'utf8'
              482 Query     DESCRIBE `cms_model_image`
              482 Query     SELECT `cms_model_image`.* FROM `cms_model_image` WHERE (((`cms_model_image`.`id` = 962)))
              483 Connect   zslon_sweetbread@localhost on zslon_sweetbread
              483 Query     SET NAMES 'utf8'
              483 Query     DESCRIBE `cms_model_image`
              483 Query     SELECT `cms_model_image`.* FROM `cms_model_image` WHERE (((`cms_model_image`.`id` = 958)))
130211 16:51:31   482 Quit
                  483 Quit
/usr/sbin/mysqld, Version: 5.5.28-0ubuntu0.12.04.3-log ((Ubuntu)). started with:
Tcp port: 3306  Unix socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
Time                 Id Command    Argument
/usr/sbin/mysqld, Version: 5.5.28-0ubuntu0.12.04.3-log ((Ubuntu)). started with:
Tcp port: 3306  Unix socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
Time                 Id Command    Argument
/usr/sbin/mysqld, Version: 5.5.28-0ubuntu0.12.04.3-log ((Ubuntu)). started with:
Tcp port: 3306  Unix socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
Time                 Id Command    Argument
/usr/sbin/mysqld, Version: 5.5.28-0ubuntu0.12.04.3-log ((Ubuntu)). started with:
Tcp port: 3306  Unix socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
Time                 Id Command    Argument
/usr/sbin/mysqld, Version: 5.5.28-0ubuntu0.12.04.3-log ((Ubuntu)). started with:
Tcp port: 3306  Unix socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
Time                 Id Command    Argument
/usr/sbin/mysqld, Version: 5.5.28-0ubuntu0.12.04.3-log ((Ubuntu)). started with:
Tcp port: 3306  Unix socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
Time                 Id Command    Argument
/usr/sbin/mysqld, Version: 5.5.28-0ubuntu0.12.04.3-log ((Ubuntu)). started with:
Tcp port: 3306  Unix socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
Time                 Id Command    Argument
/usr/sbin/mysqld, Version: 5.5.28-0ubuntu0.12.04.3-log ((Ubuntu)). started with:
Tcp port: 3306  Unix socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
Time                 Id Command    Argument
/usr/sbin/mysqld, Version: 5.5.28-0ubuntu0.12.04.3-log ((Ubuntu)). started with:
Tcp port: 3306  Unix socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
Time                 Id Command    Argument
/usr/sbin/mysqld, Version: 5.5.28-0ubuntu0.12.04.3-log ((Ubuntu)). started with:
Tcp port: 3306  Unix socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
Time                 Id Command    Argument
/usr/sbin/mysqld, Version: 5.5.28-0ubuntu0.12.04.3-log ((Ubuntu)). started with:
Tcp port: 3306  Unix socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
Time                 Id Command    Argument
/usr/sbin/mysqld, Version: 5.5.28-0ubuntu0.12.04.3-log ((Ubuntu)). started with:
Tcp port: 3306  Unix socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
Time                 Id Command    Argument
/usr/sbin/mysqld, Version: 5.5.28-0ubuntu0.12.04.3-log ((Ubuntu)). started with:
Tcp port: 3306  Unix socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
Time                 Id Command    Argument
/usr/sbin/mysqld, Version: 5.5.28-0ubuntu0.12.04.3-log ((Ubuntu)). started with:
Tcp port: 3306  Unix socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
Time                 Id Command    Argument
/usr/sbin/mysqld, Version: 5.5.28-0ubuntu0.12.04.3-log ((Ubuntu)). started with:
Tcp port: 3306  Unix socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
Time                 Id Command    Argument
/usr/sbin/mysqld, Version: 5.5.28-0ubuntu0.12.04.3-log ((Ubuntu)). started with:
Tcp port: 3306  Unix socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
Time                 Id Command    Argument
/usr/sbin/mysqld, Version: 5.5.28-0ubuntu0.12.04.3-log ((Ubuntu)). started with:
Tcp port: 3306  Unix socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
Time                 Id Command    Argument
```

Can't understand... Regular queries,  but then for some reason somewhat repeating "/usr/sbin/mysqld, Version: 5.5.28-0ubuntu0.12.04.3-log ((Ubuntu)). started with:
Tcp port: 3306  Unix socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock". What is this? Is this an attempt to restart or what? If I do "sudo service mysql restart", it works fine. What the cause, how to fix this?

Comment: post mysql error.log and/or syslog.

Comment: /var/log/mysql.err is blank, what do you mean as 'syslog' ?

Answer (score 0):

From the symptoms you posted, I think you run out of disk space in /var

If it is not the case, enable core dump for the MySQL server.
Before you start the server, run:

```
ulimit -c unlimited
```

Then after a crash, search for files named "core". The you can run a gdb backtrace to see the stack at the crash.